# How to compile a users inserted code?

Tags: java, swing, compilation, jframe

I am creating an application (Netbeans JFrame Application) that teaches programming. (Java, C, Python) My Application is a running JFrame Application and I was wondering if there was a way I compile a users code in a running JFrame Application? (I don't want it to just compare against a string as I will be doing other lessons rather than just print lines... I want to do more complicated things later on, this is why I need a compiler)

For example I want the user to print out "Hello World!" Obviously it is:

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

I want this to run through a compiler, compile, come back as correct (no errors) and say "Yes, well done on the answer" for example.
Is there any way I can compile a users inserted code? (I know of [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)) But I can't seem to get this working.

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried using Runtime#exec() to call javac?

Comment: Not that I know of, can you elaborate with more detail/links to how to's?

Comment: You can get a compiled class file by first saving the code to a file, and then calling Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac filename.java"); I'm not sure how you would then run it within your existing program, though

Comment: How would I save user input to a file with class/imports, and everything, as well as the users code? I cant seem to get my own .javas to execute at the moment

Comment: Standard library imports would still work, as javac can find them. If the user code comprises multiple classes, you could all write them to one file and remove imports. It's won't be pretty, but no one is ever going to read it anyway. Third-party code would be more problematic, you'd probably have to provide javac with the same classpath you are running your program with,